# Diffraction and the treatment of Complex conjugate in a summation function

Tags: diffraction

I understand that for the wave function ($\Psi$(r)),  |$\Psi$(r)|$^2$ = $\Psi$*(r)$\Psi$(r) and that in exponential form this is:

|$\Psi$(r)|$^2$  = A*e$^{-ik.r}$Ae$^{ik.r}$

which leads to the result: |$\Psi$(r)|$^2$ = |A|$^2$

I am using this to follow a text: by Andrew Boothroyd, Principles of Neutron Scattering from Condensed Matter.  He starts with the above treatment on waves, but then I get lost in the Introductory Chapter (which is worrying!). He describes a scattering geometry where R is the position vector of a detector D relevant to a scattering nucleus at O, and where r$_j$ represents the position vector of the n$^{th}$ nuclei in the sample relative to the nucleus at O.

[image: Nuclei scattering spherical waves toward a detector]

He then expresses the scattering from the sample as follows:

$\Psi$(R)$_{sc}$ = e$^{-ikR}$ $\Sigma$$\_{j}$$\frac{-b_j}{|R-r_j|}$ e$^{iQ.r_j}$
where b$_j$ is the scattering length of the jth nuclei.

I think I understand this. We take a plane wave of unit amplitude and the scattered wave is the sum of the scattered spherical waves emanating from those scattering nuclei subject to their position in the sample and their scattering cross-section.

But I am struggling to understand the next step....

He describes the intensity at the detector (I(Q)) as the modulus of the scattered wave, |$\Psi$(R)|$^2$, and I am told that I can approximate |R-r$_j$| by R because R >> r$_j$ which is fine, but I struggle to get:

$$I(Q) = |\Sigma_jb_je^{iQ.r_j}|^2$$

I can get rid of the first term in $\Psi$(R)$_{sc}$ (e$^{-ikR}$) by multiplying by its complex conjugate, but why doesn't the 2nd imaginary term disappear as well?  I want to multiply it too by its complex conjugate but I guess I should not?  And if I should not why is there no R denominator to the answer for I(Q)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of alternatives, I think the solution is that:

$$|e^{ikr}|^{2} = 1$$

because this is equivalent to multiplying by its complex conjugate.

That leaves the term in the Sum and |R-r$_j$| is R as R>>r$_j$ and hence can be regarded as a constant so  we can say that

I(Q) is proportional to |$\sum b_j e^{iQ.r}|^2$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).